How to change "Edit in Notepad" to launch a different editor to edit batch files in Windows 11's File Explorer?
In Windows 11's File Explorer, right-clicking on a batch file displays the menu item "Edit in Notepad" in the context menu. How to change this to edit the batch file in another text editor?
Please note that I am not referring to the extended context menu visible when SHIFT+right-clicking on a batch file in File Explorer or by clicking "Show more options".

Have you tried this?

Open regedit.
Example: Keyboard shortcut Win + R → type regedit → click OK and if prompted by User Account Control, click Yes to proceed.

Navigate to -
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command

Check (Default) key's Data.
Is it %SystemRoot%\System32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1?

If yes, then replace it with -
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
Keep the quotation marks.
In case of portable app, replace the above with path to notepad++.exe.

Click OK and test.



Thanks for your answer. Yes, I've already made that change.  Doing so changed the extended context menu (available via SHIFT+right-click), but not the standard context menu.
